# Composite Design Patten : Implemented example right or not? If not then provide suggestions for require changes

Tags: java, design-patterns

Currently I'm learning design pattern. Based on that I create one example of composite design pattern as given below. As per my understanding it gives a proper replay but not sure it's fulfill the fundamental or not. So, Can some one please cross verify it once? And ping me if some changes require.

Thanks in Advance :)

Employee.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

Composite.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Composite<E> {
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private List<E> list;
}
```

CompositeMain.java

```
public class CompositeMain {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee emp1 = new Employee(1, "Jay");
    Employee emp2 = new Employee(1, "Ajay");
    Employee emp3 = new Employee(1, "Vijay");
    Employee emp4 = new Employee(1, "Sanjay");
    Employee emp5 = new Employee(1, "Dhananjay");
    Employee cto = new Employee(0, "Boss");

    List<Object> acc = new ArrayList<Object>();
    acc.add(emp1);
    acc.add(emp2);
    List<Object> hr = new ArrayList<Object>();
    hr.add(emp3);

    List<Object> dev = new ArrayList<Object>();
    dev.add(emp4);
    dev.add(emp5);

    Composite<Object> deptAcc = new Composite<Object>(1, "Account", acc);
    Composite<Object> deptHr = new Composite<Object>(1, "Account", hr);
    Composite<Object> deptDev = new Composite<Object>(1, "Account", dev);

    List<Object> ind = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ind.add(deptAcc);
    ind.add(deptHr);

    List<Object> aus = new ArrayList<Object>();
    aus.add(deptDev);

    Composite<Object> regionInd = new Composite<Object>(1, "Indian Region", ind);
    Composite<Object> regionAus = new Composite<Object>(1, "Australian Region", aus);

    List<Object> company = new ArrayList<Object>();
    company.add(regionAus);
    company.add(regionInd);
    company.add(cto);

    Composite<Object> myCompany = new Composite<Object>(1, "Company", company);

    System.out.println("\nFull Company : ");
    System.out.println(myCompany);

    System.out.println("\nRegion : ");
    System.out.println(regionInd);

    System.out.println("\nDepartment : ");
    System.out.println(deptAcc);

    System.out.println("\nEmployee : ");
    System.out.println(hr);

  }
}
```

Comment: Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern, in your implementation, there is no clear whole-part relationship. In addition, the composite and the individual are not treated same way.

Comment: As per example of wiki, if I replace generic composite class to normal one. And create another two class RegionCompsition and Dept which extend Composite class then it become same. But in such case how it becomes more effective?

Comment: The idea of the pattern is to enable handling of the composite and the leaf object the same way. Visualize a tree, where the nodes which are non-leaf and the nodes which are leaf have same way of handling.